# Eigenvector of a linear combination of operators is an eigenvector of each operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Assume $H$ is a Hilbert space and $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are operators with Hermitian adjoints $a_1^*,\dots,a_n^*$, satisfying the canonical commutation relations. Define $N_j=a_j^*a_j$. Assume $v$ is an eigenvector of $\sum N_j$.

Is $v$ an eigenvector of each $N_j$? How can we see that a common eigenvector exists for the $N_j$'s?

**Edit:** The canonical commutation relations are $[a_i,a_j]=[a^*_i,a^*_j]=0, [a_i,a^*_j]=\delta_j^i$

Comment: What are the "cannonical commutation relations"?

Comment: The canonical commutation relations are $[a_i,a_j]=[a^*_i,a^*_j]=0, [a_i,a^*_j]=\delta_j^i$, Mr. @Lewis.

Comment: Just as I suspected!  Got no answer yet, still a-thinkin' on it!  Thanks!